# How to link 'no result behaviour' to node?

Tags: 7, views

When editing a view, i'm faced with a difficulty.
There's an image field, in the field settings i set the images (submitted when creating the node) to be linking to the node.
The problem is that in set up a default image in the no result behaviour setting.

```
<img alt="No Image" class="no-img" src="/sites/default/files/img-custom/no-image.gif" height="190px" />
```

I'd like this 'default image' to be linking to the node as well.

Any ideas on how to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way would be to set up a default image for the field. This setting is on the field settings page for the field on the node.

OR

You could to use tokens in the view. Add the path field to the view (set it to not visible), make sure it is higher than the image field. Then you should be able to add an anchor tag around your image tag and use the token value. eg.

```
<a href="[path]"><img alt="No Image" class="no-img" src="/sites/default/files/img-custom/no-image.gif" height="190px" /></a>
```

OR

You could to use tokens in the view like this. Add the path field to the view (set it to not visible), make sure it is higher than the image field. Under the 'rewrite results' section, check 'Output this field as a link' and add the link path token there.